# Hook and main program communication

Tags: c#, hook, dll-injection

There are a lot of articles with information how write hooks to add some specific functionality to other programs or change program behavior. But I not understand what should I do to send data from hook to my program.

My English not so good so I write small example: 
There are my application(myApp) and not my application(notMyApp). I want to get to the myApp text from chat window from notMyApp. I can write hook for notMyApp using [MHOOK](http://codefromthe70s.org/mhook23.aspx) for example. The question is how tom send chat text from hook to myApp?

Should I use pipes or something other things?

P.S. I prefer to use C#

Comment: Can you give a simple code example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: If you want pipes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx (Anonymous pipes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx)

Comment: I have no code yet. Is it good idea to use pipes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods of [interprocess communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

1. Pipes (my choice)
2. Shared memory / File mapping (you can map same region of "page file" to both processes)
3. Windows message `WM_COPYDATA` (slow, but easiest)

and so on... read msdn article for more information